# Plot sphere and points from file

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, import

I've been trying to plot spheres and points, given the (c_x, c_y, c_z) centre coordinates of the sphere and (x, y, z) coordinates of the points, like this:

```
    Show[Graphics3D[
  {
   {PointSize[Medium], Point[{{-261.6645, 2.3550077, -2.069712}}]},
   {PointSize[Medium], Point[{{-263.8915, 0.4822703, -2.371802}}]},
   {Opacity[0.5], Red, Sphere[{-260.072, 3.06565, -1.28551}, 3.4/2]},
   {Opacity[0.5], Sphere[{-262.5363, 0.7417043, -2.528322}, 3.4/2]}
   }
  ],
 Axes -> True]
```

My goal now is to do the same but for more points and spheres and in a more automatic way: I have a file (points.txt) that has the (x,y,z) values of all points I want to plot, each coordinate has its column, and another file (sphere.txt) which has the coordinates of the centre of every sphere I also want to plot (again each coordinate is in a separate column)

Is there an easy way to indicate that Graphics3D (or another function?) must plot every point from points.txt and sphere in sphere.txt?

Points.txt:

```
ID  X   Y   Z
0   -457.7842   0   0
1   -394.908    0   0
2   -345.2658   0   0
3   -326.8692   0   0
4   -256.3814   0   0
5   -203.4865   0   0
6   -132.9539   0   0
7   -63.00377   0   0
8   185.97179   0   0
9   209.24666   0   0
10  438.78941   0   0
11  -62.70032   0.8898561   1.9836796
12  -57.64477   2.9849146   3.2990784
13  -256.9517   0.3147554   0.310139
```

Spheres.txt

```
SphereID  X   Y    Z
0   -263.7371   0.2212362   -1.553052
1   -393.6699   0.3578  -2.478324
2   -263.3724   -7.979184   -0.449041
3   -261.0845   3.0958525   1.9232374
4   -256.401    -1.259318   -0.081782
5   186.51078   1.0394365   -0.505206
```

Comment: Please post parts of your data point.txt and sphere.txt.

Comment: Hi @cvgmt, I edited the main post to include what you asked. Thank you.

Comment: What are the radii of your spheres?

Comment: Hi @Syed, sorry, all spheres have a radius of 1.7 in the unit used in the files.

Comment: `points = Import["points.txt", "Data"][[2 ;; -1]][[;; , 2 ;; -1]];
spheres = Import["sphere.txt", "Data"][[2 ;; -1]][[;; , 2 ;; -1]];
Graphics3D[{{PointSize[Medium], 
   Point@points}, {Opacity[0.5], Red, Sphere[#, 3.4/2]} & /@ spheres},
  Axes -> True]`

Comment: Hi @cvgmt, thank you, that was exactly what I needed. Can you just help me understand what this "[[2 ;; -1]][[;; , 2 ;; -1]]" means?

Comment: @Joao  Read the `Part` function in document (use F1 key )can find such usage. For example, `{x,a,b,c}[[2;;-1]]` get `{a,b,c}`.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. The introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.

Answer (score 3):

Since the data contain the firt row and first colum,we need to remove it,so we extract the data from the `2` row to the end `-1` and from `2` colum to the end `-1`. For example

```
data = {{x, x, x, x}, {y, 1, 2, 3}, {y, 4, 5, 6}, {y, {7, 8, 9}}}
data[[2;;-1,2;;-1]]
```

> `{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {{7, 8, 9}}}`

```
points = Import["points.txt", "Data"]
points = points[[2 ;; -1, 2 ;; -1]]
spheres = 
 Import["sphere.txt", "Data"][[2 ;; -1, 2 ;; -1]]; 
Graphics3D[{{PointSize[Medium], 
   Point@points}, {Opacity[0.5], Red, Sphere[#, 3.4/2]} & /@ spheres},
  Axes -> True]
```

Comment: Thank you @cvgmt, your previous comment pointing to where to read also helped!